# Place a cursor (for editing) in datagridview cell text using a right click

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

Im trying to piece together vb.net code that will allow the user to right click in a datagridview and then place a cursor (or is it a caret?) into the text of the cell.
I can already get the row and cell using

```
 Dim hti As DataGridView.HitTestInfo = sender.HitTest(e.X, e.Y)
```

and isolate the right click on a mouse down

```
If e.Button = Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Right Then
```

I also have the position where the user right clicked using

```
Dim pt As Point = Me.PointToClient(Control.MousePosition)
```

what seams to elude me is how to put it all together to place the cursor where the user right clicked.

What I don't want is to place a cursor into a cell just anywhere, I need to place a cursor into the cells text (if any is there) where the user right clicked in the cell.

The point of the code will be to allow the user to place some text into the cell at the clicked position based on a selection from a right click menu. Appreciate any helpful suggestions.

Kind regards
Michael

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this possibly... should work reasonably well.

In your `DataGridView` `CellMouseDown` event handler:

```
    If e.Button = MouseButtons.Right Then
        'Get coordinates within cell
        _point = New Point(e.X, e.Y)
        'we are going to handle setting the edit state of the cell
        _handleEdit = True
        'Set current cell to the one we right clicked in (this will trigger the CellEnter event)
        dataGridView1.CurrentCell = dataGridView1(e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex)
    End If
```

In your `DataGridView` `CellEnter` event handler:

```
If _handleEdit Then
    'enter edit state
    dataGridView1.BeginEdit(False)
    'set the seletionstart property based on position
    CType(dataGridView1.EditingControl, TextBox).SelectionStart = CType(dataGridView1.EditingControl, TextBox).GetCharIndexFromPosition(_point)
    'Done handling the edit state
    _handleEdit = False
End If
```

Comment: the code looks like it will work, however it is not returning the correct position from the _point. I know this because when I assign an absolute vale to the SelectionStart the cursor is placed exactly where it's mean to be, when I use the GetCharIndexFromPosition its not right by longshot. So I just need to figure out how to get the location.